# Mongoose migrate

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, migrate

Anyone got a migrate module that they use to migrate mongodb data with the mongoose plugin?

I am currently using the 'migrate' module and it works great except for the fact that I need to create/destroy my connection in each up/down.

I.E.

```
// Setup mongoose
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , Role = require('../models/role')
  , User = require('../models/user');

exports.up = function(next) {
  // get a brand new connection for this patch.
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sagedb');

  var adminUser = {
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'admin'
  };

  User.createUser(adminUser, function(err, user) {
    if (err)  {
       mongoose.disconnect();  // Make sure to close connection
       return next(err);
    }

    mongoose.disconnect(next); // Make sure to close connection
  });
};

exports.down = function(next) {
  mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/sagedb'); // new connection for down

  User.getUserByUsername('admin', function(err, user) {
    if (err) {
      mongoose.disconnect(function() { // make sure to close connection
        return next(err);
      });
    }

    if (!user) {
      mongoose.disconnect(); // make sure to close connection
      return next();
    }

    User.deleteUser(user, function(err, user) {
      console.log('deleted user');
      mongoose.disconnect(next); // make sure to close connection
    });
  });
};
```

Probably a much better way to do this.  Wondering if the only option is to create my own module that starts the connection once and closes it when all patches are complete.

I have seen mongoose-migrate which tracks migration in database collection.  Not really specific to mongoose IMHO, I would rather still use the .migrate file but only have to open the connection once.

Answer (score 2):

The reason of the issue is that you have connection "connected" each time, on every ,migration
That is why you have to disconnect.
The same situation if you replace connect with mongoose.createConnection. you will need to close it.

How to solve?

move

```
  var mongoose = require('mongoose')
       , Role = require('../models/role')
       , User = require('../models/user');
```

into module like db

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
      , Role = require('../models/role')
      , User = require('../models/user');
module.exports = mongoose
```

and just require it

```
      var mongoose = require('./db')
```

So you will have:

- Single connection
- All models loaded in one place
- Clean code in
  migrations

Answer (score 0):

You can also try my [migrate-mongoose](https://github.com/balmasi/migrate-mongoose) migration framework which provides the mongoose connection right out of the box.

in your `up` or `down` function you can just access your models like this

```
this('user').findOne({ name: 'Sergey' });
```

It also persists your migrations to the database instead of the file system.

Answer (score 0):

You also have east migration framework that is very powerful and it also has mongoDB adaptors:
https://github.com/okv/east

Then you will crate migration with command:

```
east create my_migration_name
```

And then your migration scripts will look like this:

```
exports.migrate = function(client, done) {
    var db = client.db;
    db.........
    done();
};

exports.rollback = function(client, done) {
    var db = client.db;
    db.........
    done();
};
```